# MongoDB: Counting how many items with a given value exist in an array, that's in a document?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, database

I have a document that looks something like this

```js
{
  name : james,
  books : [
    {
      title: title1,
      year: 1990
    },
    {
      title: title2,
      year: 1990
    },
    {
      title: title3,
      year: 1991
    }
  ]
}
```

Say if I want to count how many books james owns with the year of 1990, how would I go about doing that? I've tried the following. But I realized it doesn't work because 'books' is an array.

```js
db.collection(collectionName).find({name:james, books: {year: 1990}}).count(function(book_count){
  console.log(book_count);
  }
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

I did see on another answer than you can use this code below to get the size of the whole array. But I am wondering how to get a count of items in the array with a particular parameter. ie. instead of seeing how many books james owns. I want to know how many of james' book are published in 1990.

```
db.mycollection.aggregate({$project: { count: { $size:"$foo" }}})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: count the number of items in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387969/mongodb-count-the-number-of-items-in-an-array)

Comment: Seriously, if there is only one document to be returned from this then the aggregation framework ( which can get the size from the array and filter it down first as well ) would be a poor choice here. Better to just test the size of the array returned in the document matching your condition instead. `db.collection(collectionName).findOne({ "name": "james", "books.year": 1990 },function(err,result) { console.log( result.books.filter(function(book) { return book.year == 1990 }).length) })`. Pretty simple stuff. Only aggregate when you intend to and what to use that number for further totals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aggregation framework is ideal for such. Consider running the following pipeline to get the desired result.

```
pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "name": "james",
            "books.year": 1990
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "numberOfBooks": {
                "$size": {                  
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$books",
                        "as": "el",
                        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.year", 1990 ] }
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
];
db.collection.pipeline(pipeline);
```

The above pipeline uses the new **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)** operator available for MongoDB 3.2 to produce an array which meets the specified condition i.e. it filters outer elements that do not satisfy the criteria. The initial **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline is necessary to filter out documents getting into the aggregation pipeline early as a pipeline optimization strategy.

The **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** operator which accepts a single expression as argument then gives you the number of elements in the resulting array, thus you have your desired book count.

---

For an alternative solution which does not use the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)** operator not found in earlier versions, consider the following pipeline operation:

```
pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "name": "james",
            "books.year": 1990
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "numberOfBooks": {
                "$size": {                  
                    "$setDifference": [
                        {
                            "$map": {
                                "input": "$books",
                                "as": "el",
                                "in": {
                                    "$cond": [
                                        { "$eq": [ "$$el.year", 1990 ] },
                                        "$$el",
                                        false
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        [false]
                    ]                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
];
db.collection.pipeline(pipeline);
```

The **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline stage involves fittering the books array so that you remove the documents which do not have the year 1990. This is made possible through the **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** and **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operators.

The **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operator in essence creates a new array field that holds values as a result of the evaluated logic in a subexpression to each element of an array. The **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** operator then returns a set with elements that appear in the first set but not in the second set; i.e. performs a relative complement of the second set relative to the first. In this case it will return the final books array that has elements with year 1990 and subsequently the **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** calculates the number of elements in the resulting array, thus giving you the book count.

---

For a solution that uses the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator, bearing in mind that (thanks to this insightful response from @BlakesSeven in the comments):

> Since there is only a single document returned with nothing but a null
>   key and a count, there is no more chance for this breaking that limit
>   than the previous operation with the same output. It's not that
>   $unwind "breaks the limit", it's that it "produces a copy of each
>   document per array entry", which uses more memory ( possible memory
>   cap on aggregation pipelines of 10% total memory ) and therefore also
>   takes "time" to produce as well as "time" to process.

and as a last resort, run the following pipeline:

```
pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "name": "james",
            "books.year": 1990
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$books" },
    {
        "$match": { "books.year": 1990 }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
]
db.collection.pipeline(pipeline)
```

Comment: The reasons to not use `$unwind` here do not include the 16MB BSON limit. Since there is only a single document returned with nothing but a `null` key and a count, there is no more chance for this breaking that limit than the previous operation with the same output. It's not that `$unwind` "breaks the limit", it's that it *"produces a copy of each document per array entry"*, which uses more memory ( possible memory cap on aggregation pipelines of 10% total memory ) and therefore also takes "time" to produce as well as "time" to process.

Comment: You also seem to have copied the `$map`/`$setDifference` example from another post since the fields are not related to this question.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Yes, it's from one of my answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/34763109/122005. Thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$elemMatch` in projection to retrieve the document with only the matching books.

```
db.collection(collectionName).findOne({name:james, books: {year: 1990}}, { books: { $elemMatch: { year: 1990 } } }). // returned document will only contains books having the year 1990.
```

If you want only the count then you need to use `aggregation` framework. First match the documents, then unwind the books array, then match against `year` field. Something like following should work:

```
db.collection(collectionName).aggregate([{$match: {name: "james"}}, {$unwind:"$books"}, {$match:{"books.year":1990}}]
```

Comment: `$elemMatch` is only ever going to return **one** match, just like all projection operators.