# Count elements of array that match a condition

Tags: mongodb

This is the simplified version of a collection I'm working on:

```js
> use tdb
> db.tcol.insertMany([{"pid": 1, "type": "simple", "variations": []}, {"pid": 2, "type": "simple", "variations": []}, {"pid": 3, "type": "variable", "variations": [{"vid": 1, "instock": false}, {"vid": 2, "instock": true}, {"vid": 3, "instock": true}]}, {"pid": 4, "type": "variable", "variations": [{"vid": 1, "instock": false}, {"vid": 2, "instock": false}]}, {"pid": 5, "type": "variable", "variations": [{"vid": 1, "instock": true}]}])
> db.tcol.find({}, {"_id": 0}).pretty()
{ "pid" : 1, "type" : "simple", "variations" : [ ] }
{ "pid" : 2, "type" : "simple", "variations" : [ ] }
{
        "pid" : 3,
        "type" : "variable",
        "variations" : [
                {
                        "vid" : 1,
                        "instock" : false
                },
                {
                        "vid" : 2,
                        "instock" : true
                },
                {
                        "vid" : 3,
                        "instock" : true
                }
        ]
}
{
        "pid" : 4,
        "type" : "variable",
        "variations" : [
                {
                        "vid" : 1,
                        "instock" : false
                },
                {
                        "vid" : 2,
                        "instock" : false
                }
        ]
}
{
        "pid" : 5,
        "type" : "variable",
        "variations" : [
                {
                        "vid" : 1,
                        "instock" : true
                }
        ]
}
```

And I'm trying to count the number of elements in `variations` arrays that are in stock (`"instock": true`), which in this example would be 3, `{"pid": 2, "vid": 2}`, `{"pid": 2, "vid": 3}`, and `{"pid": 5, "vid": 1}`.

Also, only records with `"type": "variable"` have variations, so I have to filter on that as well.

In order to count, I saw that I can use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/#aggregation) and [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-a-query-condition-on-a-field-embedded-in-an-array-of-documents) to return only those records that have at least one document with `"instock": true` in `variations` array:

```js
> db.tcol.aggregate([{"$match": {"type": "variable", "variations.instock": true}}, {"$project": {"_id": 0}}])
{ "pid" : 3, "type" : "variable", "variations" : [ { "vid" : 1, "instock" : false }, { "vid" : 2, "instock" : true }, { "vid" : 3, "instock" : true } ] }
{ "pid" : 5, "type" : "variable", "variations" : [ { "vid" : 1, "instock" : true } ] }
```

Now if use [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) like this, I will get 2, which is just *records that have at least one document with instock of true in variations array*.

```js
> db.tcol.aggregate([{"$match": {"type": "variable", "variations.instock": true}}, {"$group": {"_id": null, "count": {"$sum": 1}}}])
{ "_id" : null, "count" : 2 }
```

But I'm trying to count all elements of this array that are in stock and return the sum for all records of `tcol`. How can I do that?

Comment: can you show your expected result format..

Comment: @turivishal The expected result is just the number 3, or `{"_id" : null, "count" : 3}`.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876100/mongodb-counting-how-many-items-with-a-given-value-exist-in-an-array-thats-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match` your conditions
- `$filter` to iterate loop pf `variations` and filter by `instock`
- `$size` to get total elements in above filtered result
- `$group` by null and sum total elements from above size

```
db.tcol.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "type": "variable",
      "variations.instock": true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total: {
        $sum: {
          $size: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$variations",
              cond: { $eq: ["$$this.instock", true] }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YGUSWZJiUaG)